# can't find grub folder in /boot

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I recently picked up a small size SSD that I wanted to put into my laptop via a CD drive bay adapter. After getting everything installed and set up I set up a clonezilla thumb drive so I can clone the system partition for my old HDD onto my new SSD.

I have had to make a few modifications here and there such as making sure that the UUID on my old partition is changed and for some reason even the disc identifier was the same between both drives... but even though I tried reading through web search results to find out if there's any special changes they need to be done with grub but I didn't find much.

I went ahead and rebooted my system with the BIOS focus being on the SSD but grub says that there is no partition to be found and won't boot.
If I use my arch Linux install thumb drive and arch-chroot into my system, I am able to find the boot kernels and initram FS files and even the grub folder is there, everything is there. I made sure that my FS tab is correct with the proper UUIDs, I do have a separate boot partition but it is configured correctly as far as I can tell. And I even run the **grub-make config** command to make sure that everything is up to date.
When I reboot I still get the grub rescue: *there is no partition* error. Using the grub rescue console I'm able to see both of my drives and all the partitions, but if I `ls` into my boot partition, my kernel images and initram FS files are there but mysteriously there is no grub folder.

Does anybody know why the grub folder will be present when I arch-chroot into my system but it's not there when Grub tries to boot from that same partition?

I'm sorry if I have left out any details. I am trying to upload this quickly and to be honest after spending a day trying various solutions and reading various websites that explain how grub works I have all but decided just to scrap my system and boot partitions and reinstall later tonight or tomorrow, probably not with a separate boot partition this time. I'm sure I heard somebody say a while ago that having a separate boot partition was beneficial but I don't know if I need it on this older Toshiba laptop and I also feel like it's one more layer of headache that I don't need at this time

what follows is a continuation of my journey with this problem:

as I was thinking about it today, it occurred to me that with my separate boot partition I have to declare it exists through my FS tab, and it has to mount on every boot up. or maybe what I mean to say is if I didn't have a boot partition that was separate grub would simply look in my system partition for the boot folder... this led me to the line of thought that if I'm already planning to reinstall without a separate partition, maybe what I should try before I do that is to arch- chroot into my system as it currently is. and if I again find all my files plus the grub folder intact on that boot partition, even though when my system boots up normally grub can't seem to find that grub folder, maybe I can just create a boot folder in my system partition and copy everything into it. then of course i would comment out the line in my fstab that tells the system to mount /boot from a separate partition. i will try this tonight, i hope it works

so last night I was able to arch-chroot into my system and everything that I think I need was there in the boot folder. I went ahead and proceeded with my as previously stated plan. My system was still not able to boot and using the grub rescue console I did see everything was in its proper place. I was able to load modules and boot my system with the normal command but I don't know why it will not work without these manual steps. I don't know if it's because both drives are still in the system, I was planning on keeping my old drive as a data drive and I have not erased my old system partition yet because I wanted to make sure that there was not any issues with the new one. and my new ssd is in the optical disc Bay adapter but since I was able to boot from my hard drive when it was connected through that same sata connection I didn't see any reason why that would be a hindrance. this is definitely a puzzle that I cannot find the solution for, but at this point I think I am ready to fresh install and hope that sledge hammer solution takes care of everything..

Comment: where did you change the UUID's/identifiers? on the old or the new drive?

Comment: I changed the UU ID on the original system partition on my old HDD. I figured since the UUID in my FS tab already matched with my newly cloned system partition on my SSD that it would make more sense to randomly reassign the old one.